# Colour Issues in OS X Terminal ssh'd to Ubuntu terminal

Tags: macos, ubuntu, colors, terminal.app

In the OS X Terminal.app, I'm having some colour issues.

If I am working locally, there are no colours.

If I ssh into my opensolaris machine (using screen inside ssh) there are no colours.

If I then ssh into my ubuntu virtualmachine, and say, vim edit a file, the colours are completely broken. On quitting vim, it then keeps the broken colours and applies them to everything until I force a terminal bell.

I assume this is a misconfiguration of the ubuntu machines colours, or a mismatching of terminal emulators. What is the best fix in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to run `export TERM=vt100` when connecting to the Ubuntu machine. A good fix would be to find out what the value is *supposed* to be for Terminal and use that instead.

Comment: vt100 works, however it removes all colours. perhaps someone could recommend a term for use in osx/opensolaris/ubuntu to keep some consistency?

Comment: I use `TERM=rxvt`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way/the way I do it is put `export TERM=xterm-color` in my `~/.bashrc`, and colours work perfectly with my Ubuntu 9.10 SSH connections. (The problem is caused by Ubuntu assuming the terminal is `xterm`, not `xterm-color`).

Comment: See i attempted this, seeing that xterm-color was the selection in the terminal settings, but i still get the same issues. Same broken colours (in the basic terminal i get yellows,pinks and blues on a grey background) which stick around on the prompt after whatever generated them (vim) has been exited.

Answer (score 0):

If you fell in this question in stack, this helped me a lot:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add this:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
# Enable colors in bash
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxBxCxDxexegedabagaced
```

and so,

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

thanks to:
https://medium.com/@json_singh/ubuntu-like-terminal-in-mac-bash-9afe37b09aa